# How do you make a moveable element, and bound it to screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple web page with a cartoon image that the user can move around. I'd like to move the image with arrow keys, and then bound that movement to the available screen / window / document size with jQuery. In the code below, the constants at lines 1 - 4 aren't working, and I can't see why!

```js
let width = Math.max($(document).width(), $(window).width());
let height = Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height());
let height = $(window).height();
let width = $(window).width();

//Below is code which allows for the character to move: 
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    document.write(Math.max($(document).height(), $(window)
        .height()));
    document.write(Math.max($(document).width(), $(window)
        .width()));
    switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        // Left arrow key pressed             
        case 37:
            if ($('img').position().left > 0) {
                $('img').animate({
                    left: "-=20px"
                }, 'fast');
            }
            break;
            // Up Arrow Pressed             
        case 38:
            $('img').animate({
                top: '-=20px'
            }, 'fast');
            break;
            // Right Arrow Pressed             
        case 39:
            if ($('img').position().left < width) {
                $('img').animate({
                    left: '+=20px'
                }, 'fast');
            }
            break;
            // Down Arrow Pressed             
        case 40:
            $('img').animate({
                top: '+=20px'
            }, 'fast');
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you make an working jsfiddle of it? Or at least post your html?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've made a codepen of the whole lot of this: https://codepen.io/the-looper-man/pen/oOvmOY